# variable references & in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In the following code, I noticed `&$list` is passed by reference in the loop, however `$user` and `$request` are passed by variables. Passing `$list` directly to the loop won't change `$list` outside the loop scope.

```
    public function index(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $list = collect();
        $someRelations()->each(function ($val) use (&$list, $request, $user) {
            // mutate $list
        });
        dd($list);
    }
```

Why is this?

Comment: What's your concern here? If you passed the variable by reference, if you change `$list` inside the `each` closure it will also change outside the closure.

Comment: in php if you put the variable in and make changes in the loop you don't need the reference

Comment: @aceraven777 If I change it to `$list`, the `$list` remains empty outside the loop but actually updates inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually its the core PHP functionality rather than Laravel itself, basically when you are passing variables without reference, it actually clone the variable with the same name but in different locations. So, if you make any changes to it, there will be no changes to the value of the variable outside the scope.

**Without reference**

```
$x = 10;
(function() use ($x){
    $x = $x*$x;
    var_dump($x); // 100
})();
var_dump($x); // 10
```

But, if you pass the value by reference, instead of creating a new variable, it provides the reference to the same original variable. So, any changes made inside the function will change the value of the variable outside scope as well.

**Pass by reference**

```
$y = 10;
(function() use (&$y){
    $y = $y*$y;
    var_dump($y); // 100
})();
var_dump($y); // 100
```

To know more about it you could visit, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php